# Garbage collection - root nodes

Tags: garbage-collection, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have recently read bits and pieces about garbage collection (mostly in Java) and one question still remains unanswered: how does a JVM (or runtime system in general) keeps track of CURRENTLY live objects?

I understand there objects are the ones which are currently on the stack, so all the local variables or function parameters, which ARE objects. The roblem with this approch is that whenever runtime system checks what currently is on the stack, how would it differentiate between a reference variable and simple int? it can't, can it?

Therefore, there must be some sort of mechanism to allow runtime to build initial list  of live objects to pass for mark-sweep phase...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer provided by greyfairer is wrong. The JVM runtime does not gather the root set from stack by looking at what bytecodes are used to push data on the stack. The stack frame consists of 4 byte(32bit arch) slots. Each slot could be a reference to a heap object or a primitive value such as an int. When a GC is needed, the runtime scans the stack, from top to bottom. For each slot, it contains a reference if:

a. It's aligned at 4 byte boundary.

b. The value in the slot point to the region of the heap(between lower and upper bound).

c. The allocbit is set. The allocbit is a flag indicating whether the memory location corresponding to it is allocated or not.

Here is my reference: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibm/library/i-garbage2/.

There are some other techniques to find the root set(not in Java). For example, because pointers are usually aligned at 4/8 bytes boundary, the first bit can be used to indicate whether a slot is a primitive value or pointer: for primitive values, the first bit is set to 1. The disadvantage of this is that you only have 31bits(32 bits arch) to represent the integer, and every operations on primitive values involves shifting, which is obvious an overhead.

Also, you can make all types including int allocated on the heap. That is, all things are objects. Then all slots in a stack frame are then references.

Comment: So all in all it is pretty low level differentiation, rather than JVM? But JVM has a Reference type declared for the bytecode, so why not use that? You're sure that it is so low level rather than on the byte code level?

Comment: As for as I know (based on both the link I gave earlier, and the browsing of codes of several JVM implementations), I'm sure that my understanding is right. You can simply diving into the GC codes of some open source JVM implementations to check this. They all need to walk the stack to find out the reference. However, maybe the criteria used to verify whether a  slot is reference or not is slightly difference (Most of them verify a. and b. For c, it's really based on implementation).

Comment: As why not use bytecode, this is my understanding(not sure whether it's right or not). GC is a runtime thing, but bytecode are generated at compile time and static. When a GC happens, the runtime system need to find out the roots and follow them to find out live objects. . To do this, you have to actually check the value in each stack frame slot, even you know that this slot contains a reference at compile time(as greyfairer said, you know this by looking at the bytecode). Because you need to know the exact reference value to find other objects in the heap.

Comment: So why bother to check the bytecode?  You have to walk the stack anyway.

Comment: Where does the allocbit reside? When somewhere outside of the object, you'd increase the allocation overhead (by just one operation, but it's significant). When inside of the object, then you may be misinterpreting other data as the allocbit and run into problems mention on the bottom of [this article](https://www.excelsiorjet.com/blog/articles/conservative-gc-is-it-really-that-bad/).

Comment: @maaartinus well, that now-dead link surely described IBM’s JVM, if it was about Java at all. Since we already know that it never applied to the HotSpot JVM, the only remaining question is, whether it still applies to IBM’s JVM. That’s the kind of answer we get, when we ask what “Java” does, when it is actually about a JVM implementation specific behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The runtime can perfectly differentiate between reference variables and primitives, because that's in the compiled bytecode.

For example if a function f1 calls a function f2(int i, Object o, long l), the calling function f1 will push 4 bytes on the stack (or in a register) representing i, 4 (or 8?) bytes for the reference to o, and 8 bytes for l. The called function f2 knows where to find these bytes on the stack, and could potentially copy the reference to some object on the heap, or not. When the function f2 returns, the calling function will drop the parameters from the stack.

The runtime interpretes the bytecode and keeps record of what it pushes or drops on the stack, so it knows what is a reference and what is a primitive value.

According to http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/thinkinginjava/abitaboutgarbagecollection.html, java uses a [tracing garbage collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Tracing_garbage_collectors) and not a reference counting algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With that in mind, how does garbage collection proceeds when it is initiated by JVM? how does it actually locates root nodes - jumping back on the stack or does it have a separate collection of nodes?

Comment: See article link for an in-depth dissection.

Comment: I found the following sentence in the article you referred 'Mark and sweep follows the same logic of starting from the stack and static storage and tracing through all the handles to find live objects.' What are these mystic handles they refer to...

Comment: Handles, pointers, references, all the same to me. It means that the runtime indeed keeps a list of locations on the stack that are references/pointers to objects on the heap, and from there it finds pointers to other objects that are referenced by these objects and so on...

Comment: Ah, OK, then auxiliary data structure is being used... That makes sense !

Comment: What the interpreter does is pretty irrelevant as significant parts of the code get compiled into machine language. So your solution as it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The HotSpot VM generates a GC map for each subroutine compiled which contain information about where the roots are. For example, suppose it has compiled a subroutine to machine code (the principle is the same for byte code) which is 120 bytes long, then the GC map for it could look something like this:

```
0 : [RAX, RBX]
4 : [RAX, [RSP+0]]
10 : [RBX, RSI, [RSP+0]]
...
120 : [[RSP+0],[RSP+8]]
```

Here `[RSP+x]` is supposed to indicate stack locations and `R??` registers. So if the thread is stopped at the assembly instruction at offset 10 and a gc cycle runs then HotSpot knows that the three roots are in `RBX`, `RSI` and `[RSP+0]`. It traces those roots and updates the pointers if it has to move the objects.

The format I've described for the GC map is just for demonstrating the principle and obviously not the one HotSpot actually uses. It is not complete because it doesn't contain information about registers and stack slots which contain primitive live values and it is not space efficient to use a list for every instruction offset. There are many ways in which you can pack the information in a much more efficient way.

Comment: This map is only needed at safepoints rather than on arbitrary offsets (which may be the reason for your gaps between 0, 4, and 10). I've just found [this article](https://www.excelsiorjet.com/blog/articles/conservative-gc-is-it-really-that-bad/) supporting your answer.