# How to throw an Exception when your method signature doesn't allow to throw Exception?

Tags: java, exception, checked-exceptions

I have a method like this:

```
public void getSomething(){
...
}
```

I want to throw an `Exception` inside `getSomething()`. The compiler will not allow me to do that because my method doesn't allow `Exception` to be thrown in there. But I need to throw a subclass of `Exception` for my testing **(I can't throw Unchecked `Exception`)**. This is clearly a hack but I need it for my testing. I tried EasyMock but it doesn't allow me to do that either. Any ideas how to do that?

Thanks,
Sean Nguyen

Comment: You are testing something that is impossible to happen. Why?

Comment: I tried to mock soap response using LogicalHandler<LogicalMessageContext>. The handleMessage(LogicalMessageContext context) doesn't declare throws Exception. But all the exception throws by the soap end point are subclass of Exceptions. I need to throw those exception to mock my service response.

Comment: See my edit in case you're interested.

Comment: Why you couldn't throw Unchecked exception? I can't understand what you were trying to do. What kind of test framework are you using? You can catch unchecked exceptions normally in your tests.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Method 1:**

[This post by Alexey Ragozin](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/10/java-how-to-throw-undeclared-checked.html) describes how to use a generics trick to throw an undeclared checked exception. From that post:

```
public class AnyThrow {

    public static void throwUnchecked(Throwable e) {
        AnyThrow.<RuntimeException>throwAny(e);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static <E extends Throwable> void throwAny(Throwable e) throws E {
        throw (E)e;
    }
}
```

The trick relies on `throwUnchecked` "lying" to the compiler that the type `E` is `RuntimeException` with its call to `throwAny`. Since `throwAny` is declared as `throws E`,  the compiler thinks that particular call can just throw `RuntimeException`. Of course, the trick is made possible by `throwAny` arbitrarily declaring `E` and blindly casting to it, allowing the caller to decide what its argument is cast to - terrible design when coding sanely. At runtime, `E` is [erased](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) and has no meaning.

As you noted, doing such a thing is a huge hack and you should document its use very well.

---

**Method 2:**

You can also use `sun.misc.Unsafe` to this end. First you must implement a method that uses reflection to return that class's instance:

```
private static Unsafe getUnsafe() {
    try {
        Field theUnsafeField = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
        theUnsafeField.setAccessible(true);
        return (Unsafe)theUnsafeField.get(null);
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

This is necessary as calling `Unsafe.getUnsafe()` will typically throw a `SecurityException`. Once you have the instance of `Unsafe` you can put its terrifying capabilities to use:

```
Unsafe unsafe = getUnsafe();
unsafe.throwException(new Exception());
```

Credit goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5648334/697449) on the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574241/interesting-uses-of-sun-misc-unsafe. I thought I'd mention this for completeness but it's probably better just to use the trick above instead of allowing `Unsafe` into your code.

---

**Method 3:**

In the comments of the linked answer about using `Unsafe`, [@bestsss points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574241/interesting-uses-of-sun-misc-unsafe/5648334#comment9695261_5648334) a much simpler trick using the deprecated method [`Thread.stop(Throwable)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28java.lang.Throwable%29):

```
Thread.currentThread().stop(new Exception());
```

In this case you would use `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` and once again document very fiercely. Again, I prefer the first trick for its (relative) cleanliness.

Comment: @PaulBellora you could always play around with the `Class::newInstance()` method, that can will throw anything the ctor does

Comment: @PaulBellora Why doesn't the first example result in `ClassCastException` at runtime?

Comment: @Demetri `(E)e` is an unchecked cast, meaning the JVM cannot fail fast if it's wrong. After type erasure the method is indistinguishable from `private static void throwAny(Throwable e) throws Throwable { throw e; }`.

Comment: `Unsafe` is just fine

Comment: @Enerccio until Java 9

Comment: Method 3 no longer works since JDK 8, because `stop(Throwable)` methow now just throw exception to the caller.

Comment: @PaulBellora but if you replace <E extends RuntimeException> you get a cast exception at runtime given an IOException, why is that?

Comment: @LudvigW the compiler's type erasure process replaces the generic type E with its upper bound. When that upper bound is Throwable, the cast works. When it's RuntimeException, it doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

Java has two kinds of exceptions, checked and unchecked. You must declare checked exceptions, but you don't have to declare unchecked exceptions.

`RuntimeException` is the basic unchecked exception, so you can throw that without declaring it.

```
public void getSomething(){
   throw new RuntimeException("I don't have to be declared in the method header!");
}
```

As a side note, you probably don't want to throw a raw RuntimeException, but subclass it to something more specific to your needs. Any subclass of RuntimeException will be unchecked as well.

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear. I need to throw a subclass of java.lang.Exception (checked exception).

Comment: @SeanNguyen RuntimeException is a subclass of Exception. It's just a special case in Java where you don't need to declare that it'll be thrown.

Comment: Sorry, not very clear again. I need to throw checked exception that is subsclass of Exception. I can't throw RuntimeException.

Comment: @SeanNguyen: please tell us why you need to throw a checked exception.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you were trying to do. You could just throw an unchecked exception inside your method and then test using JUnit like in my example below.

```
public void getSomething() {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

JUnit 4 test example:

```
@Test
public void testGetSomething() {
    try {
        getSomething();
        fail("Expecting RuntimeException!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.getLogger("test").info("Exception was caught: " + e.getClass());
    }
}
```