# Why does newInstance() return null?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

According to the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29), the `newInstance()` Method of `java.lang.Class` is not intented to return null.
But my code seems to prove the opposite. Why?

```
public Assessment createAssessment() {
    Class<? extends Assessment> assessmentClass = (Class<? extends Assessment>) assessmentClassDataTable.getRowData();
    try {
        System.out.println("ASSESSMENTCLASS " + assessmentClass);
        // -> 'ASSESSMENTCLASS class my.model.ManualSelectAssessment'
        Assessment a = assessmentClass.newInstance();
        System.out.println("ASSESSMENT " + a);
        // -> 'ASSESSMENT null'
        return a;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Application.handleError(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

It returns null.

Comment: Can the `toString` method of `ManualSelectAssessment` return `"null"`?

Comment: Presumably you are sure it's not throwing an exception, being caught and then returning null?

Comment: Make sure your class has a no-argument constructor

Comment: You're printing the results of `a.toString()`, which is not "returning" `null`. See whether `a == null`.

Comment: @Mike Good though, but no. I can be sure that the return value is null.

Comment: @DaveRlz Yes, I'm sure because `System.out.println("ASSESSMENT " + a);` is executed.

Comment: there is something in your tostring method that doesn't have value, when you instantiate with the default constructor.

Comment: @All - you were all right. `toString` returns null. Shame on me.
I will delete this useless question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

newInstance() never returns `null`.  However `newInstance().toString()` can return `"null"`

Note: One gotcha with newInstance() is that it can throw a CheckedException !

```
public Main() throws IOException {
    throw new IOException();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    Main.class.newInstance(); // throws IOException silently.
}
```

Even though IOException is a check exception, the compiler has not idea the newInstance() will throw this checked exception.  If you try to catch it the compiler will complain it cannot be thrown !!

Comment: Wouldn't the `IOException` be wrapped in the `InstantiationException`?

Comment: InstantiationException is when `the class object represents an abstract class, an interface,
  an array class, a primitive type, or  void
OR the class has no nullary constructor`  There is an `ExecutionException` for this when calling `Constructor.newInstance()`

Comment: Interesting, I always though it functioned like `InvocationTargetException`. That's definitely a gotcha.

Comment: @PaulBellora One of four ways to throw a CheckedException without the compiler knowing (without JNI) :P

Comment: I'll have to update [an answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11943139/697449) about that, thanks for teaching me something.

Comment: @PaulBellora A puzzle for you, can you guess another three ;)