# View bytes at specific place in memory in Java

Tags: java, c, memory, byte

In C I might say

```
printf("%p",0x11194);
*((int *) 0x11194) = 30240;
```

(In this example I know that there is an integer at that memory location)

Please tell me, how would I do the same in Java? Btw I may have completely misunderstood how memory works

Comment: You can't look at memory in java. Its a managed language.

Comment: Learn how to write printf in C: it should be `printf("%p",...`

Comment: You can't. direct memory access like that does not exist in Java.

Comment: You don't **need** memory access in Java.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt comments, I shall use C instead @grijesh If I did not need it, I would not have asked

Comment: You shouldn't ever need to use it, but the [`sun.misc.Unsafe`](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/misc/Unsafe.html) class provides direct memory access.

Comment: You may well want to use Java and sun.misc.Unsafe and/or ByteBuffer for direct memory access. See my answer for more details etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* do this in Java using [sun.misc.Unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574241/interesting-uses-of-sun-misc-unsafe) and [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html).

However for normal Java usage you don't do this at all. Java will give you an object reference, which is handle to an object. It doesn't point to one place in memory (the JVM can move objects in memory without you knowing/caring) and you can't perform arithmetic on them (unlike pointers)

Answer (score 1):

You have not misunderstood how memory works; you have merely assumed that Java will let you touch it.  It won't.  The memory and pointers are still there, but must be accessed through proper Object creation and dereferentiation, as opposed to direct pointer memory access.

On the bright side, you don't really have to worry about freeing memory that you no longer need though.