# Java TCP/IP Socket write performance optimization

Tags: java, performance, tcp, socket.io, low-latency

**Server Environment**

```
Linux/RedHat
6 cores
Java 7/8
```

**About application :**

We are working on developing a low latency (7-8 ms) high speed trading platform using Java. Multi-leg orders are sent after algo conditions are met

**Problem**

The orders to the exchange using TCP/IP `java.net.Socket` APIs (using `java.io.OutputStream.write(bytes[] arg0)` ). Profiler measurement is records as 5-7 microsec which is very high as per our low latency reqs. We are not made use of setPerformancePreferences() api as suggested in one of the questions posted in stacktrace.

**Question**

1. Any alternatives to java.net.Socket to reduce the socket
   transmission time?
2. Any optimization techniques to improve performance
3. Is setPerformancePreferences() is of any use?

Answer (score 5):

> We are not made use of setPerformancePreferences() api

It doesn't do anything and never has. I wouldn't worry about it.

> Any alternatives to java.net.Socket to reduce the socket transmission time?

The problem is most certainly not a software one.  You can get <8 micro-seconds from Java to Java on different machines, but you need low latency network cards like Solarflare or Mellanox.

If you want fast processing you should consider either a high GHz haswell processor, possibly over clocked to 4.2 or 4.5 GHz or a dual socket Haswell Xeon.  The cost of these compared to the cost of trading is not high.

> Any optimization techniques to improve performance

Using non-blocking NIO i.e. ByteBuffers and busy waiting on the socket connections. (I wouldn't use Selectors as they add quite a bit of overhead) I would turn off nagle.

For some micro-tuning, use an affinity bound thread on an isolated cpu.

> Is setPerformancePreferences() is of any use?

Looking at the source .. I will let you be the judge.

```
public void setPerformancePreferences(int connectionTime,
                                      int latency,
                                      int bandwidth)
{
    /* Not implemented yet */
}
```

> Java 7/8

In term of which version to use, I would start with Java 8 as it has much improved escape analysis which can reduce garbage of short lived objects and thus help reduce latency between GCs and jitter from GCs.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things come to mind:

[JNI](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html):  JNI lets you write C code that is ran from your Java code.  Critical parts of your Java code that are running to slow can be migrated to C/C++ for improved performance.  Work would be needed to first identify what those critical points are and if its worth the effort to move it to C/C++.

[Java Unsafe](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/misc/Unsafe.java.html):  Wanna get dangerous?  Use Java Unsafe to bypass that pesky GC.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574241/using-sun-misc-unsafe-in-real-world) is more info on it.  On Github you may find some cool wrapper code to more-safely use Java Unsafe.  [Here is one.](https://github.com/nickman/UnsafeAdapter)  [More info.](http://mishadoff.com/blog/java-magic-part-4-sun-dot-misc-dot-unsafe/)

[LMAX Disruptor](http://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/):  Read more about it [here](http://martinfowler.com/articles/lmax.html).  This company is also building a fast trading system in Java.  Disruptor allows for faster inter-thread communication.

Bytecode scrutinization:  Review your code by looking at the byte code.  I have done this for a video game I made and was able to streamline the code.  You'll need a good tool for turning your class files into readable bytecode.  [THis might be the tool i used.](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/JBVD-Java-Bytecode-Viewer-Decompiler.shtml)

Improved garbage collection:  Have you tried using the [G1 garbage collector](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/g1-javas-garbage-first-garbage-collector/219401061?pgno=2)?  Or messing around with the [older GC's](http://www.softwaresecretweapons.com/jspwiki/thelastjavagarbagecollectionguideyouwilleverneed)?

[Highscalability](http://highscalability.com/):  This site is full of good info on making code fast.  [Here is an example that might help.](http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/5/13/the-secret-to-10-million-concurrent-connections-the-kernel-i.html)

[New API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_API)  I dont know exactly how to use New API, but it has come up in articles I have read.  [Here is another article on it.](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/napi)  You might need to use it via JNI.